# Rails 'includes' and 'where' with belongs_to and has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have models:

```rb
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_paper_trail

  enum status: %i[created in_process]

  has_many :order_containers
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_paper_trail

  enum status: %i[in_process collected]

  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :variant
end

class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_paper_trail

  has_many :line_items

  belongs_to :product

  validates :barcode, presence: true
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_paper_trail

  belongs_to :isles, required: false
  has_many :variants

  validates :name, :volume, :sku, :price, presence: true
end

class Isle < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_paper_trail

  has_many :products
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

I need to output only those orders in which the products belong to a specific island. For example, if there are no products in the order that belong to the island I need, then this order and its products do not need to be displayed. And if there are products in the order that belong to a specific island for example (isle.id 1), then such an order needs to be withdrawn and those products that belong to this department

I try this:

```
@products = Order.includes([:line_items, :variants, :products, :isles]).where('products.isle_id = isle.id').references(:orders)
```

but i got error:

```
ailure/Error: return { "#{root_name}": [] } if records.blank?
 
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "products"
   LINE 1: ..."orders" WHERE "orders"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (products.i...
```

I'm sorry if I didn't design well, I'm a novice developer, and here's my first assignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return all products in Order#1 from Isle#1. If order has multiple variants from the same product it will return duplicate products, if this is not what you need add `.distinct` to these queries.

```rb
>> order = Order.first
>> isle  = Isle.first

>> Product.joins(variants: { line_items: :order }).where(isle_id: isle, line_items: { order_id: order })
=> [#<Product:0x00007f1551fc4820 id: 1, isle_id: 1>,
    #<Product:0x00007f1551fc4258 id: 2, isle_id: 1>]
```

You can add a few associations to `Order` to simplify this:

```rb
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items

  has_many :variants, through: :line_items
  has_many :products, through: :variants
end
```

```rb
>> Order.first.products.where(isle_id: Isle.first)
=> [#<Product:0x00007f154babcb30 id: 1, isle_id: 1>, 
    #<Product:0x00007f154babca18 id: 2, isle_id: 1>]
```

**Update**

Make sure you're creating the associations correctly. Use `create!` and `save!` methods in the console to raise any validation errors.

```
# NOTE: create a new order with two products in two different isles
#       just add the required attributes from your models.

order = Order.create!(line_items: [
  LineItem.new(variant: Variant.new(product: Product.new(isle: (isle = Isle.create!)))),
  LineItem.new(variant: Variant.new(product: Product.new(isle: Isle.new)))
])

# NOTE: verify that you have two products

>> order.products
=> [#<Product:0x00007f6f1cb964e0 id: 1, isle_id: 1>,
    #<Product:0x00007f6f1cb963f0 id: 2, isle_id: 2>]

# NOTE: filter by isle

>> order.products.where(isle_id: isle)
=> [#<Product:0x00007f6f1ccda630 id: 1, isle_id: 1>]

>> order.products.where(isle_id: 2)
=> [#<Product:0x00007f6f1d140cd8 id: 2, isle_id: 2>]
```

---

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many*

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association*

Comment: It's return empry array(
#<Product id: 1703, name: "expedita", sku: "T0098321C", volume: 0.468e1, price: 0.2154e2, deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2022-07-11 08:25:38.113553000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-07-11 08:25:38.117404000 +0000", isle_id: 8>]>
(byebug) Isle.all
[#<Isle id: 8, name: "officia", deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2022-07-11 08:25:38.116167000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-07-11 08:25:38.116167000 +0000">]>
p = Order.first.products.where(isle_id: Isle.first)
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>

Comment: @Aleksandr I've updated the answer. you're only showing me a product and an isle, I can't tell you why result is empty from that. make sure you have `Order.first.products`. if everything is set up correctly, you should be able to navigate from  Order to Isle like this: `order.line_items.first.variant.product.isle`

Comment: thanks you!!! It's work. But i have one more question. Now I need to output orders and display only those products from the order that belong to this island

Comment: `Order.includes(:products).where(products: { isle_id: 1}).flat_map{|o| p o; p o.products }`

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few issues with the structure of that. If you truly just want the products for a specific Isle then you should be able to just use:

`@products = Product.where(isle_id: my_isle_variable)`

You also probably need to update the models so that Product `belongs_to :isle` (singular not plural)

Comment: I need to pull out of the order products that belong to a certain island

Comment: ok, simplify things by breaking it up. I think you may have other issues with the way your associations are defined on the models.


`# First get the products for the order
@products = Product.joins(variant: [line_item: :order]).where(order: my_order)

puts @products.inspect
# Examine the output to see if it is giving you the correct products for the order

# Then filter it by the Isle
@products = @products.where(isle_id: my_isle_id)`

Comment: Thanks Brain, but i can't undarstand what it means 'where(order: my_order)'